# Can ABCL's Interpreter load Lisp source from an InputStream?

Tags: java, lisp, common-lisp, abcl

I've just started looking at [ABCL](https://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/) to mix some Lisp into Java. For now, loading some Lisp from a file will be sufficient, and I've been looking at the [examples](https://abcl.org/svn/trunk/abcl/examples/). In every case, the pattern is:

```
Interpreter interpreter = Interpreter.createInstance();
interpreter.eval("(load \"lispfunctions.lisp\")");
```

But say I'm building a Maven project with a view to packaging as a JAR: how can I load `lispfunctions.lisp` from `src/main/resources`? I can easily get an `InputStream`—can I go somewhere with that? Or is there another idiom I'm missing here for loading Lisp source from a resource like this?

Comment: This is probably not the best way, but you can eval the lisp code compile or load your .lisp. Like "(load-file \"lispfunctions.lisp\")".

Comment: I think the reason you haven't found a specific function to do what you want is because it can be done through the general Lisp Object interface. 

Since `load-file` is a lisp function, it is a lisp object. You can access it through the lisp-object java interface as well. I think it would go something like 

`Packages.findPackage("CL").findAccessibleSymbol("FIND-PACKAGE").getSymbolFunction().execute("lispfunctions.lisp");` 

I don't know if you have to do something special with the "lispfunctions.lisp" string to make it a lisp object.

Comment: Great question. As you say, you can get an InputStream for the file in the jar. I see that the CLHS says (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm) that LOAD can take a stream as the source. So it looks to me that the question is just how to get a Common Lisp stream from a Java InputStream, and then supply that to LOAD.

Comment: Some tinkering suggests that you can create a Lisp stream via `new Stream(Symbol.SYSTEM_STREAM, f, Symbol.CHARACTER)` in Java, where `f` is a `InputStream`.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I can now get a `Stream`, but what next? To be clear, all I'm trying to do is something like [this example](https://abcl.org/svn/trunk/abcl/examples/java-to-lisp-2/Main.java). How do I get the `CL-USER` `Package` and call Lisp functions from Java, as in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten the following to work. I am working with ABCL 1.7.0 on MacOS, although I'm pretty sure this isn't version-specific.

```
/* load_lisp_within_jar.java -- use ABCL to load Lisp file as resource in jar
 * copyright 2020 by Robert Dodier
 * I release this work under terms of the GNU General Public License
 */

/* To run this example:
$ javac -cp /path/to/abcl.jar -d . load_lisp_within_jar.java
$ cat << EOF > foo.lisp
(defun f (x) (1+ x))
EOF
$ jar cvf load_lisp_within_jar.jar load_lisp_within_jar.class foo.lisp
$ java -cp load_lisp_within_jar.jar:/path/to/abcl.jar load_lisp_within_jar
 *
 * Expected output:
(F 100) => 101
 */
import org.armedbear.lisp.*;
import java.io.*;

public class load_lisp_within_jar {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            // It appears that interpreter instance is required even though
            // it isn't used directly; I guess it arranges global resources.
            Interpreter I = Interpreter.createInstance ();

            LispObject LOAD_function = Symbol.LOAD.getSymbolFunction ();

            // Obtain an input stream for Lisp source code in jar.
            ClassLoader L = load_lisp_within_jar.class.getClassLoader ();
            InputStream f = L.getResourceAsStream ("foo.lisp");
            Stream S = new Stream (Symbol.SYSTEM_STREAM, f, Symbol.CHARACTER);

            // Call COMMON-LISP:LOAD with input stream as argument.
            LOAD_function.execute (S);

            // Verify that function F has been defined.
            Symbol F = Packages.findPackage ("COMMON-LISP-USER").findAccessibleSymbol ("F");
            LispObject F_function = F.getSymbolFunction ();
            LispObject x = F_function.execute (LispInteger.getInstance (100));
            System.out.println ("(F 100) => " + x.javaInstance ());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println ("oops: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the program first gets the function associated with the symbol LOAD. (For convenience, many, maybe all of COMMON-LISP symbols have static definitions, so you can just say `Symbol.LOAD` instead of looking up the symbol via `findAccessibleSymbol`.) Then the input stream is supplied to the load function. Afterwards we verify that our function F is indeed defined.

I know this stuff can be kind of obscure; I'll be happy to try to answer any questions.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Works here. Thanks for getting me over the line.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.